# Python- KeyError 'C' on list checking values

Tags: python

I am trying to create a code that assigns values to letters in words, and then spit them back out in pythonm. This is my code:

```
import time
import os
import string
os.system('cls')
values = dict()

for index, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase):
    values[letter] = index + 1


def scramble(letter):
   i = 0
   phrase = list(letter)
   mylist = []
   while i < len(phrase):
      list.append(values[phrase[i]])
      i = i + 1
   print(res)
   
scramble("Crapx")
```

Well doing this I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Code\Python\fibbanaci.py", line 22, in <module>
    scramble("Crapx")
  File "d:\Code\Python\fibbanaci.py", line 18, in scramble
    list.append(values[phrase[i]])
KeyError: 'C'
PS D:\Code\Python>
```

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: The dictionary only contains lowercase letters, but `Crapx` has an uppercase `C`.

Comment: Assuming your input is going to be a variable, you can call lower on the input string. `scramble("Crapx".lower())`

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary values map string.ascii_lowercase letters to index + 1. It has no key with upper case letters. Infact, you could do,

```
def scramble(letter):
   i = 0
   phrase = list(letter.lower())
   mylist = []
   while i < len(phrase):
      mylist.append(values[phrase[i]])
      i += 1
   print(phrase)
```

or;
Even though the values dictionary in the global namespace, as a habit, it is good to introduce variables which will be used inside the function (compound structure) as parameters to the function.

```
import time
import os
import string

os.system('cls')
values = {letter: index for index, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)}

def scramble(letter, values):
    print [values[char] for char in letter.lower()]

scramble("Crapx", values)
```

Comment: Hey, that did help, but it didnt completely fix the issue. I ended up tweaking the code to find the working code of
```def scramble(letter):
   i = 0
   phrase = list(letter.lower())
   mylist = []
   while i < len(phrase):
      mylist.append(values[phrase[i]])
      i = i + 1
   print(mylist)
   ```

Comment: Do you still get an error..? or what is your expected outcome..?

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary doesn't have uppercase keys. You can use `string.ascii_letters` instead of `string.ascii_lowercase`.

```
import time
import os
import string
os.system('cls')
values = dict()

for index, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_letters):
    values[letter] = index + 1

def scramble(letter):
   i = 0
   phrase = list(letter)
   mylist = []
   while i < len(phrase):
      mylist.append(values[phrase[i]])
      i = i + 1
   print(mylist)
   
scramble("Crapx")
```